# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom, foreach

I am trying to get the `<td>` from a specific row, but I always encounter the `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error.

MY CODE:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($notes); #$notes - value of textarea
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$moths = $rows->item(0)->nodeValue; #first row
$mothlast = $rows->item($rows->length - 1)->nodeValue; #lastrow

foreach ($moths as $moth) 
{
    $cols_mother = $moth->getElementsByTagName('td'); trying to get the columns of the first row of table
    $rli_mother = strip_tags($cols_mother->item(0)->nodeValue);

    echo $rli_mother; #first row
}
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated. thank you!!!

Comment: Make sure `$moths` actually has a value and is an array before you try to loop through it

Comment: yes it has a value. it is actually the first row of my table.

Comment: Are you sure? PHP doesn't seem to think so.

Comment: Im actually getting the desired row whenever I print it... how do i get the tds/columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    $td = ....
```

$moths is not an array of `<tr>`s, but $rows is

If you're wanting the first row only then just use

```
$first = $rows->item(0);
```

This will return the whole node and allow you to use it, where as nodeValue just returns a string containing the value

Comment: then how would I get the columns only of the first row?

Comment: I only wanted the first column of the first row.. how wwould I get it?

Comment: Take what I've given you and try something. And read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: thank you so much!! I just changed $moths = $rows->item(0)->nodeValue; to $moths = $rows->item(0); then parsed the tds. thanks so much!!:)

Comment: Remember to accept if it answered your question. And upvote too!